# disable second mouse click, that clicked immediately.

Tags: linux, drivers, mouse

My mouse is corrupt. So that sometimes when I click one time, it is clicked two times itself.
Double-click happen when I just clicked once.
How can I disable mouse click, for 0.5 second, that after every mouse click.

Comment: Does it happen with a different mouse?  I think you're trying to solve a hardware issue with a really bad software patch.

Comment: my touchpad works fine. and also I see this in another Linux desktop(laptop).

Comment: With the same mouse or another one?

Comment: with same mouse

Comment: Mice doesn't cost that much, buy a new instead of trying to workaround it with a nasty hack that will end up annoying you. When I doubleclick I'm pretty sure the clicks are far less than half a second apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common issue with a defective mouse is the clicking which works on and off or starts to click by itself or double-click when you click.

Any software patch will only waste your time as it would be very annoying to work with and the situation will continue to deteriorate.